# Group by applied seperately for each type of column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The table I'm working on is as follows :
[Table in Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zuvw.png)

What I want to do is to Group By 'Month' for each Person, that is use the Group By statement multiple times for each person. I want the output as follows :

[Required Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91W9J.png)

Please tell me how I can achieve this. Thank you.

I tried looking for some for loop syntax in mysql so I could loop through each person and apply group by each time and join but that just seemed too complicated and I though there must be an easier way.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! does `group by person, month` doesn't satisfy your need?

Comment: Since people like me who refuse to click on unknown links and land un known sites will be unable to understand or even solve your question, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and follow the instructions.

Comment: @JonasMetzler sorry about this I thought that stackoverflow would reproduce as an image. Although you could have inspected html of page to know the link :)...I guess this is some site which stackoverflow is using to host images?

Comment: @BagusTesa Yep it does thnx!...I though that 'group by' would only allow having Distinct values in the column it is induced on so thought that wouldnt work....but i guess it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should give you the desired results:

```
SELECT  PERSON,
        SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
        MONTH
FROM    table
GROUP BY MONTH, PERSON
ORDER BY PERSON, MONTH DESC
```

Comment: thnx!...I though that 'group by' would only allow having Distinct values in the column it is induced on so thought that wouldnt work....I thought only one 'A'/'B'/... would be allowed in Person field if group by is used on that column...I haven't learnt MySQL systematically so not rlly strong in the basics :(